# Add blank row after page-break in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to add blank rows after every single page-break that the table is having, can it be done?

I am not sure it can be achievable or not. If yes, it is , please share some insight.

Comment: So you want to add a blank row at the top of every page apart from the first one? Why?

Comment: @BIDeveloper Actually, I have tried adding another tablix to blend with the existing tablix. But it is not what I want-the rows are appearing only at the end. The main idea is to have the same number of rows in every pages. [link] (http://tinypic.com/r/zxqtdy/9) This is my grouping: [link] (http://tinypic.com/r/2vcvkvc/9)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a blank row under your header, and set the header to appear on every page.

Right click the Tablix -> Tablix Properties -> Under the "General" tab, make sure "Repeat Header rows on each page" is selected.

Comment: hmmmm I don't wanna have blank rows before the data, I want them after the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty row at the end of last record, but there is no straight forward way of doing it at the end of each page.

For inserting an empty row at the end of all the records, simply add new row by clicking 'Outside group - Below' under 'insert row' option in table.

One thing which can help in your case is, try inserting new row by clicking 'Inside group - below' option and hide/show it on the basis of some expression. You can show that blank row based on page size, eg

NumberOfRecords mod PageSize = 0;

You need to insert this type of expression by navigating to 
'Row Visibility' -> 'show or hide based on an expression'

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi

Thanks for your reply.
If the blank row is added according your suggestion, (inside group), I will be only getting the rows inside the group. I want to add row after every page-break of particular group inside the whole tablix. I think my main question posted was unclear. The result should be adding rows after page-break ,which is in between the groups inside the whole tablix. Please refer to my picture posted.

Comment: For the second part, what exactly does "Number of records" implying to? I am unable to get the number of all the records inside the tablix in this scenario-because I have subtotals.